# How do I fix this Bootstrap styling grid and alignment issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with bootstrap I cannot seem to fix.
Please have a look at: [my bootply sample](http://www.bootply.com/AKLKvD1YBW)

I want each "canvas" to have some gap but whenever I try to wrap any of the 3 within a `.row`, it looks fine on browsers. alignment issues arise whenever the view-port shifts to a smaller one. It's usually the canvas' within the col-*-3 that is much wider than the "main" canvas.

any suggestions on how to deal with this ?

Comment: If you want to maintain the layout you have on smaller screens as well, use `col-xs-3` wherever you have `col-md-3` along with it so that the same layout is maintained. I suspect the second column occupies its own row and that causes those canvases to be of the same width as the main canvas.

Comment: @phreakv6 I'm not after maintaining the layout on smaller screens. what happens is, with the current code, the 2nd column (`col-md-3`), is rendered after the 1st column both of which spans the entire 100% width. problem is, the 2nd column, has this "rogue" padding/margin I can't figure out entirely

Comment: Rows add a 15px padding by default. And col-md-3 might occupy same space as a col-md-9 on smaller devices. This might be your problem.